# Typescript: record of KeyType -> value types

Tags: typescript, record

I need to create a Typescript `Record` with the keys defined in an independent type and specific types for each value.

The keys are defined as follows:

```
// Keys must be available/iterable at runtime
const keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const
export type Key = typeof keys[number]
```

Now I see two options, both flawed.

Option 1: repeat the keys and define the value types explicitly, as needed. Flaw: `Structure` isn't actually based on `Key` and they might deviate.

```
export type Structure1 = {
  a: number
  b: boolean
  c: string
}
```

Option 2: define a record from `Key` and lose the specific type information on the values:

```
export type Structure2 = Record<Key, number | boolean | string>
```

Is there a third option for a `Structure3` that uses `Key` as the key type *and* an explicit value type per key?

Comment: Why second option is bad?

Comment: Because `Structure2` would accept `boolean` or `string` for `a`

Comment: Are you looking for defining value types as a tuple (`[number, boolean, string]`) and "zipping" with the keys by order?

Comment: In this case you need to have some map type

Comment: Interesting: `export type Structure3 = Record<Key, any> & { a: number, b: boolean, c: string }` doesn't seem to work, but `export interface Structure3 extends Record<Key, any> { a: number, b: boolean, c: string }` does - I always thought these were just two different ways of saying the same thing; apparently not; can someone explain? Still no perfect solution because the interface definition might contain more keys than `Key` though :-(

Comment: What I do in this kind of mix is break the specifics using the union operator, take ```Structure1``` for instance, you could have ```{ a: string } | { b: number } | { c: boolean}``` so the keys are bound to the value, but not tied to each other.

Comment: @AlekseyL. the value type shouldn't be one tuple for all values; each key/value pair should have one specific value type. Yet I need an iterable array of all keys at runtime. And ideally these two types should be interdependent.

Comment: Then you can define an object and extract type and keys from it https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDeAoGMCGAuGARgBosYAjAqAJwFcBTU7YAgcmmoEswBzVjAL4YMUAJ4AHejADKNWsCi1qU1GMkg48RAG4MoSLADW9URBQwA8uQBW9BQDpjpgBQIQASlxnnTjTLkKSvTuANoAutpAA

Comment: Here's what I meant by values tuple https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBA1gUwJ4RgXhgbQOQENsA0M2ARoccNgLoy6qiRQBQUSADgjAGq4A2ArglQZMYfgFsSCAE5Fo0gJZgA5kRIgQvBLjBUmLdpwDSyYTFYcQAM3imDHGCaTpHp0RKnS99zgGUo0vzAUPzSnBgA3jAAtGG4ACbgvM6YRjBKtkjWrii0qGkIAB5QCGDxqAAGACQRYpIyAL4VMAD8ORCpNABcMGAIAG4yVD08AkKdMA36APQAVLNMMLMwPjD+gcGh4TARizD7uD11ngDce-skPfJKymf7+8A96praYGdTS9NAA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can keep it DRY and enforce your interface keys like this (performance bonus: no extra runtime code):

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdgMwPYCcDGEDSEQGcA82IUEAHsBHACa5S7AoCWcA5gDRQAqJ5lNUAJQhpUVQjg4BXOAGs4SAO5wAfMqgBeKAG8AUFCgBtTFGZQZOJAi5QAhrWNkK1ezigB+KMYBcUOBABuECgAuj6cRsEA3DoAvtE6InD0Zji0mgYA5DYZHBkARjlQGWgZwba0ifTRoJCerpo1EJYpeAZwkgC2eUFROjoA9P1QAPIyOo1QAMoMkmjAkigQAIwasIioGEQERBy6+jY+7V1B0fp5PnlISAA2EDZwp1BoPvRMrNExyvGDIzIc91QeAwbFAwCgkJAUMBGBBaDZFlAkB1GMAKFRxuBoNMULN5osAEyreDIdBYVLiEC7PS2Q6dbooR7nKCXG53B7U550BjMFiPKi044oAxRKA-JEotFQBDgjpQRrUiAXK63e6RUVDcWoiCA6VIuWY2JfPo-GAocEoHwABXBkNARRKJloyNwuB5Jjg+sgADofVAABT4gDMABZgwBKDG1bG4hYQQNE9akrYUqn7AX0xlK1mqw3RIA)

```ts
type EnforceKeys<Key extends string, T extends Record<Key, unknown>> = {
  [K in keyof T as K extends Key ? K : never]: T[K];
};

const keys = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as const;
type Key = typeof keys[number];

// Ok
type Structure1 = EnforceKeys<Key, {
  a: number;
  b: boolean;
  c: string;
}>;

// Ok, and extra properties are omitted
type Structure2 = EnforceKeys<Key, {
  a: number;
  b: boolean;
  c: string;
  d: number[]; // omitted from type
  e: boolean; // omitted from type
}>;

// Error: Property 'c' is missing in type... (2344)
type Structure3 = EnforceKeys<Key, {
  a: number;
  b: boolean;
}>;
```